# Can you pretty this up?

Tags: python, function, math, if-statement, pygame

I have here a monstrosity of a python class method. The only way I could think to do it was a massive and ugly if / elif / else block. Can any of you come up with any ideas to make this nicer?

For context, this is part of a grid-making library for pygame, and is a function which takes one of the tiles in the grid and returns the surrounding tiles. if "horizontal" is set to false it returns only the tiles vertically adjacent to the tile, and vice-versa.

```
def getSurroundingTiles(self, tile, horizontal = True, vertical = True):
    index = list(self.getTiles()).index(tile)
    maxtile = self.sqrtnum - 1 # Offset for 0 indexing

    i = int(math.floor(index / self.sqrtnum))
    j = int(index % self.sqrtnum)

    surroundingTiles = []

    if i == 0 and j == 0:
        #Top left corner
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i][j + 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.append(self[i + 1][j + 1])
    elif i >= maxtile and j == 0:
        #Top right corner
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i - 1][j], self[i][j + 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.append(self[i - 1][j + 1])
    elif i == 0 and j >= maxtile:
        #Bottom left corner
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.append(self[i + 1][j - 1])
    elif i >= maxtile and j >= maxtile:
        #Bottom right corner
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i - 1][j], self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.append(self[i - 1][j - 1])

    elif i == 0:
        #Top border
        if horizontal: 
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i][j + 1],
                                     self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j + 1],
                                     self[i + 1][j - 1]))
    elif i >= maxtile:
        #Bottom border
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i - 1][j], self[i][j + 1],
                                     self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i - 1][j + 1],
                                     self[i - 1][j - 1]))
    elif j == 0:
        #Left border
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i - 1][j],
                                     self[i][j + 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j + 1],
                                     self[i - 1][j + 1]))
    elif j >= maxtile:
        #Right border
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i - 1][j],
                                     self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j - 1],
                                    self[i - 1][j - 1]))

    else:
        if horizontal:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j], self[i - 1][j],
                                     self[i][j + 1], self[i][j - 1]))
        if vertical:
            surroundingTiles.extend((self[i + 1][j + 1], self[i + 1][j - 1],
                                    self[i - 1][j + 1], self[i - 1][j - 1]))

    return surroundingTiles
```

Comment: Reading your code it looks like where it says `vertical` it means `diagonal` and `horizontal` actually means (`horizontal` + `vertical`). Is that right?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# indices 0 - 3 are for horizontal, 4 - 7 are for vertical
dij = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0),
       (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]

def getSurroundingTiles(self, tile, horizontal = True, vertical = True):
    index = list(self.getTiles()).index(tile)
    maxtile = self.sqrtnum - 1 # Offset for 0 indexing

    i = int(math.floor(index / self.sqrtnum))
    j = int(index % self.sqrtnum)

    surroundingTiles = []

    startat = 0 if horizontal else 4
    stopat = 8 if vertical else 4

    for di, dj in dij[startat:stopat]:
        if 0 <= i + di <= maxtile and 0 <= j + dj <= maxtile:
            surroundingTiles.append(self[i + di][j + dj])

    return surroundingTiles
```

(not tested.) It calculates the neighbor indices relatively using unit steps so that you don't have to explicitly type them out. It also tests for all of the `out of bounds` cases at once.

I'm assuming that by `horizontal` and `vertical` you mean something like `horizontally and vertically adjacent` and `diagonally adjacent`, as your code suggests.

Comment: You should combine `di` and `dj` into a list of tuples `[(0,1), (1, 0), ...]` and then your loop can just be `for ni, nj in dij[startat:stopat]:`

Comment: @Duncan Right, but perhaps this is more readable? (preference, since you can read the lists vertically to see the tuples) Anyway, both methods require approximately the same amount of code in the for loop.

Comment: I've just tested this and it works perfectly (though I moved the di and dj assignments inside the function). Would you like to be credited if I distribute this?

Comment: @user1149589 No, it's fine.

Comment: Nice and probably about as compacted as you'd want. You could do it as a single list comprehension or generator but that would definitely lose clarity. `return [self[i+di][j+dj] for di, dj in dij[0 if horizontal else 4:8 if vertical else 4] if 0 <= i + di <= maxtile and 0 <= j + dj <= maxtile]` replacing from `surroundTiles = []` onwards.

Answer (score 2):

Taking @irrelephant's idea even further (to it's logical conclusion or reductio ad absurdum, you decide):

```
d = (
    ( ( 0, 1), ( 1, 0), ( 0,-1), (-1, 0) ),
    ( ( 1, 1), ( 1,-1), (-1, 1), ( 1,-1) )
)

def getSurroundingTiles(self, tile, horizontal = True, vertical = True):
    index = list(self.getTiles()).index(tile)
    maxtile = self.sqrtnum - 1 # Offset for 0 indexing

    fhv = (horizontal, vertical)
    ij = ( int(math.floor(index / self.sqrtnum)),
           int(index % self.sqrtnum) )

    surroundingTiles = []
    for ihv in range(2):
        if fhv[ihv]:
            for k in range(4):
                n = [sum(p) for p in zip(ij, d[ihv][k])]
                if all([0 <= n[i] <= maxtile for i in range(2)]):
                    surroundingTiles.append(self[n[0]][n[1]])

    return surroundingTiles
```

Please note: This code is untested.

Comment: @irrelephant basically posted a similar re-write 30 seconds earlier.

Comment: I find this sacrifices readability.

Comment: @user1149589, yes more concise tends to be less readable. This type of code reads better when written with numpy.